# How to get the raw data of solutions of partial differential equation in mathematica

Tags: export, differential-equations

I am using NDSolve command of mathematica solving a very complicated partial
differential equation (two independents "t" and "x", three master variable "u", 
"v", "w"). Each time I solve it, it takes 10-20 minutes. So, I wish to save 
the solution into an independent file.

I used command `Export["myfile.m", nSol]`, where nSol is the output of NDSolve. 
But the resulting mayflie.m is 160Mb. It's too large and contains much redundant 
data. I wish to save only three two dimensional array u(t,x), v(t,x), w(t,x) on 
points NDSolve obtaining the solution. I think that should not be as large as 
160Mb.

Could anybody help me solving this problem?

Comment: We can help you only if you give details of the functions.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Obtaining the computed function values on the grid is accomplished with

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy`"]
datau=InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid[solu]
datav=InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid[solv]
dataw=InterpolatingFunctionValuesOnGrid[solw]
```

where `solu`, `solv`, `solw` are the `InterpolatingFunction`s produced by NDSolve.  If you need the grid too, use

```
grid=InterpolatingFunctionCoordinates[solu]
```